# En mi navegador, mi página /users/index aparece igual que /users/create

Tags: php, laravel, web

explico el título:
Estoy haciendo un trabajo personal en Laravel 8, donde estoy diseñando una página de manejo de usuarios simple (CRUD simple de usuarios) en el cual lo primero que deberías ver es una lista de usuarios, ya sean activos, administradores o proveedores, etc. como la página de inicio/index. El asunto es que cuando entro a mi página `index` de usuarios, me aparece este señor:
[image: Página /users/index]

Como pueden observar (si se puede observar bien, perdón si la calidad se presenta mal), estoy en el `index` de mi página, pero por alguna razón, veo mi página de crear usuarios.
**Controlador**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $user = User::all();
        return view('admin.user.index', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('admin.user.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        // dd($request->all());
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'confirm-password' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request['name'];
        $user->email = $request['email'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($request['name']);
        $user->isProvider = $request['isProvider'] ? true : false;
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'Usuario nuevo registrado.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Archivo de rutas: admin.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\admin\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

Si alguien conoce o sabe acerca de esto, estaría muy agradecido de saber. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tendrías que mostrar las rutas y el controlador que sirven la página del index y la del formulario

Comment: Voy a ponerlos en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver el código, cuando en **dos rutas diferentes cargan la misma página**, los casos más probables, generalmente asociados a la práctica del "copia-y-pega":

- En tu fichero/s de rutas tienes dos rutas diferentes que apuntan al mismo sitio (vista o controlador@metodo).
- Dos métodos del mismo o diferentes controladores estar cargando la misma vista.

Y si, lo anterior estuvierá bien, aunque no sería un problema de rutas sino como las usas:

- Has puesto la misma ruta en dos enlaces de tu sitio.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Pues, de todas las opciones, todo va bien. La cosa es que de estar en la vista users.create si te diriges a la vista users.index, me sigue mostrando la vista de users.create, y no entiendo lo que pasa.

Comment: "si te diriges a la vista users.index..." ¿cómo lo haces? clicando un enlace supongo, si ves el HTML ¿tiene la ruta correcta? Si la respuesta es SI, ¿tienes alguna redirección condicionada si no existen usuarios en `UserController@index`?